# How can I provide anonymous user to access my REST GET API without providing any auth information?

Tags: 8

The Drupal 8 REST UI configuration page asks me to select *Authentication providers* for *GET method*; otherwise, it doesn't allow me to export the REST request.

How can I provide anonymous user to access my REST GET API without providing any auth information?

Comment: That is done through `People -> Permissions`, but you most likely have to pick at least one authentication provider. I recommend cookie.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein, as for Drupal 8.4, seems that no permissions available to be set there.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Drupal documentation : https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/rest

> Don't forget to grant the corresponding permission! In case of a decoupled site, you typically need to grant the authenticated user role permission to GET content. In case of a web service, you typically need to grant the anonymous users permission to GET/POST content. Grant them at /admin/people/permissions#module-rest, or using Drush: drush role-add-perm anonymous 'restful  ', for example: drush role-add-perm anonymous 'restful get entity:node'

basically add the anonymous permission for the GET resource.

Comment: Does not work in Drupal 8.4

Comment: I can confirm this works in 8.5

Comment: It works on Drupal 8.9 too

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own authentication provider; it could then allow anonymous users access to your resource. It is not that difficult, the only thing I found is that you have to be careful to make sure the authentication provider only applies whe you specifically want it to. Look here for a tutorial:

http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/12/28/how-to-create-an-authentication-provider-in-drupal-8/

Comment: Again, simple thing made complicated. Why anonymous users are denied access by default in the first place. I won't run Drupal 8 ever, I just installed it to benchmark its RestFUL API against other frameworks. A benchmark, Drupal 8 surely will lose.

Comment: Just ran the benchmark: Drupal 8 = 75 requests/second vs. another new framework (not PHP based) = 550 requests/second. Amazing. There will be no Drupal 9.

Comment: @W.M. Because maybe you don't want to allow anonymous users to get access to the endpoints, this is normal, some endpoints return information that should not be public.